# Problem aligning U.I elements using a foreach loop on multiple arrays in Laravel Blade file

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, foreach, iteration

Am working on a Laravel application whereby am fetching some data from the backend and storing in 3 separate variables.Next I pass the variables to the view and need to display the data on the view in the form of a hierachy/treelike structure with Level 1 (array in variable called asm) being the highest, Level 2 (array in variable usm) being under level 1, Level 3 (array in variable ag) being under level 2.

I have tried using a foreach loop on the markup but it aint showing the expected outcome. Basically all level 1 data (shown dynamically) should be closed when the user clicks level 1,, the respective level 2 should collapse/open,, when level 2 is clicked respective level 3 should open below it.

Basically the layout should look like the layout in this link:

https://www.bootply.com/DglnYJTSKA

**Level 1 (stored in variable asm)**

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "157"
    "unit_sales" => array:7 [▶]
    "policies" => array:3007 [▶]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "73401"
    "unit_sales" => array:8 [ …8]
    "policies" => array:2226 [ …2226]
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "0"
    "unit_sales" => array:1 [ …1]
    "policies" => array:162 [ …162]
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "76300"
    "unit_sales" => array:1 [ …1]
    "policies" => array:1 [ …1]
  ]
]
```

**Level 2 (stored in variable usm)**

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "74696"
    "ag" => array:13 [▶]
    "pol" => array:481 [▶]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "1525"
    "ag" => array:8 [▶]
    "pol" => array:357 [▶]
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "47060"
    "ag" => array:1 [▶]
    "pol" => array:124 [▶]
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "74695"
    "ag" => array:3 [▶]
    "pol" => array:5 [▶]
  ]
]
```

**Level 3 (stored in variable ag)**

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "ag" => "75**"
    "pol" => array:4 [▶]
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "ag" => "9***"
    "pol" => array:27 [▶]
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "ag" => "67***"
    "pol" => array:8 [▶]
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "ag" => "224"
    "pol" => array:147 [▶]
  ]
]
```

**Foreach loop that am trying to use on the blade**

```
<div id="MainMenu">
    <div class="list-group panel">
      <!-- Level 1 -->
      @foreach($asm as $a)
       <a href="#demo3" class="list-group-item list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu" style="color: #868ba1;"> ASM ID : {{ $a['id'] }} <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

          <div class="collapse" id="demo3">
          <!-- Level 2 -->
          @foreach($usm as $u)

        <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1"> USM ID : {{ $u['id'] }} <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

        <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="SubMenu1">
            <!-- Level 3 -->
           @foreach($ag as $Agt)
            <a href="#SubSubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1"> Ag: {{ $Agt['ag'] }}<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          @endforeach
          <!-- END level 3-->
        </div>
            @endforeach 
            <!--END level 2-->
          </div>

      @endforeach
      <!-- END level 1-->
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be caused by ids like `#SubMenu1`, `demo3`
First, inspect your view to show that level one target id point to another level or not. 
You can change id dynamically by `$loop->iteration` in template like `demo{{$loop->iteration }}`